# Error 500 after login to admin

Tags: magento

I have my url set to www.YourDomain.com/store and log in via www.YourDomain.com/store/index.php/admin or www.YourDomain.com/store/admin in to the dashboard but whe I log in the first time I always get a internal server error . Once I refresh I have no issues till I would say the next session

Any one has a suggestions how to fix this ? I don't have the issue on my Local

TX

C

Comment: Hi the memory is already 512MB

Answer (score 0):

`Increase the memory limit from .htaccess file`. Thats the `main issue may be`. check for this `variable in .htaccess` in magento `root` `php_value memory_limit`